# US citizen working from india for US company

Tags: usa, india, work

I am a US citizen and working for a US company and paid in USD in my US bank.
I would like to know how long can I work  from India without troubling my company to create a corporate entity for tax purpose in India. My  US company does not have a presence in India.

Comment: Not sure what this has got to do with travel, voting to close.

Comment: The mention of "how long can I work" suggests the OP intends to use some form of short-stay visa. Perhaps the question of whether one can work for a US company while in India on e.g. a tourist visa should be answered here.